# Uk visa refusal on grounds of income

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, ghanaian-citizens

I was refused a visitors visa recently and want to reapply. We find this reason quite intangible in the sense that

I was invited for an assessment and on the letter it states that I should be in the Uk a minimum of 1 week to acclimatize with the weather so I chose 1 month 10 days as my duration.

The reason for refusal as said earlier isn't tangible. In my application i stated I'm the supervisor for a family business and I receive such amount as salary. I added the business registration certificate and his bank account. 
The case worker claims he/she doesnt know the source of cash deposits which comes clearly from daily sales.

2. In my application i stated My dad is supporting me with the stated amount yet it was interpreted as it coming from my personal income and savings and i never said i support the family financially or anyway it's a job I help.

All documents submitted are true and authentic. What's the way forward as i want to reapply

Also I have been employed recently in a government institution. How do I state that in my next application without any conflict as I used to be a supervisor and now with a different institution now?

[image: refusal note]

What do I do next when I reapply ? Should I still state I'm with the family business? Or use my new job role? 
How do we explain deposits in my dad's account. My assessment date has now been changed to November meaning i can reapply.

Kindly help me to reapply for my visa

Comment: @Kay jay If you’ve changed jobs since your refused application, you just need to provide evidence (your employment contract) with you next application. The refusal reasons given are pretty standard - see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: You inexplicably drew a line over the phrase "British Army assessment" in your image. This is relevant information and should not have been blacked out. You also should search our site for this phrase as others have asked similar questions already.

Comment: @michael I'm new here and will get used to the rules . Thank you

Comment: @Kayjay Thanks I missed it. I have closed this as a duplicate of our very informative question (and answer) on the topic. See if that helps you.

Comment: The reason could be standard but where I indicated it's my dad paying for the travel cost and it come to be from me personally. That's where I do not understand

Comment: @Kay jay Perhaps you completed the ‘cost of trip’ information incorrectly? If your father is paying all of the costs, you should state that (in the ‘Who is paying towards the cost of your visit’ section). If you’re paying some of the costs, state how much you are each paying. Having said that, if you can’t afford the trip on your own (and UKVI don’t think that you can) the need for financial support from your father weakens your application.

Comment: @Traveller 7 I stated it's my dad who is paying for the trip. I stated the amount in the section.

Comment: Does it mean one can not support you to travel especially a family member?

Comment: @Kay jay No it doesn’t (Immigration Rules 4.2e and 4.3 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) But UKVI believe that your father’s bank statements had unexplained entries so were not satisfied with his financial circumstances (the topic of proving an applicant has sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit is discussed fully in the duplicate question). IMHO if you’ve recently changed jobs, I would wait to re-apply until you can show regular income from it and that you can afford the trip from your own savings.